# Generic requirement that Some: AsyncSequence is not throwing

Tags: swift, concurrency

I would like to extend `AsyncSequence` in ways that depend on whether the sequence can throw. Neither `AsyncSequence` nor `AsyncIteratorProtocol` distinguish such sequences explicitly. Yet, the concurrency module does come with concrete sequences with throwing and non-throwing variants. The only generic difference I see is that the `next` method of non-throwing sequences are **re**throwing. Here is an example:

```swift
extension AsyncMapSequence : AsyncSequence {

    struct Iterator : AsyncIteratorProtocol {

        mutating func next() async rethrows -> Transformed?
    }
}
```

Whereas the throwing variant is a plain `throws`:

```swift
extension AsyncThrowingMapSequence : AsyncSequence {

    struct Iterator : AsyncIteratorProtocol {

        mutating func next() async throws -> Transformed?
    }
}
```

(I am not even sure how `rethrows` is even possible for a method that does not take any arguments. The only thing that comes to mind is that the curried expression of such a method could *throw* some light on that...)

So, the question is how to express something along the lines of:

```swift
extension AsyncSequence where AsyncIterator /* is not throwing */ {

}
```

Comment: `rethrows` is quite easy to understand here if you think of `async` as having a completion handler parameter...

Comment: A method like `func ƒ() async rethrows {}` would normally incur a compile time error. Extending a `AsyncSequence` in this way, however, does not. Isn't that interesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [this proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-rethrowing-protocol-conformances/42373) is fully implemented you will be able to express conformance to a failable sequence by providing some syntax sugar

```
extension AsyncSequence where nothrow AsyncIterator {
```

or

```
struct Foo<S: nothrow AsyncSequence>
```

This comes from the `@rethrows` annotation currently attached to `AsyncSequence`

```
@rethrows public protocol AsyncSequence
```